# Multi storage paths

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have server with 2 hdd. I want to use one for all media files, which are on storage/app/media for current media files and other for all files before 2018.

How can I switch storage path depends on query I make.

All media are saved on media table. I can make changes on table if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config\filesystem.php update `disk` array and add your new disks like this:

```
'public_two' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/public_two'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/public_two',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

and you call your diks like this: `Storage::disk('public_two');`

Please be free to read the [FileSystem Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem)

Comment: Yeah, I have already second disk, just trying to get an logic to use that, depends on condition.

Comment: so what is the condition to use one or another disk?

Comment: on query from db, I believe I should make custom asset() function top switch depends on query.

Comment: also second disk is on linux root /data, while app is /home/laravel/